# Como fazer uma contagem de registros por cada dia entre uma data e outra?

Tags: mysql, sql, query

Preciso fazer uma consulta, que me retorne o numero de registros cadastrados em CADA DIA, entre duas datas.

Estou usando um banco MYSQL, e tentei aqui, mas nenhuma forma me pareceu a correta.

Comment: Em que formato está a data na DB?

Comment: Data está no formato DATE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT count(*), DAYOFYEAR(colunaData) as diaDoAno
FROM tabela
WHERE colunaData BETWEEN dia and dia
GROUP BY diaDoAno
```

Answer (score 2):

Basta agrupar por dia usando `day(data)`:

```
select
    day(t.data) as 'Dia',
    count(*) as 'Quantidade'
from
    tabela t
where
    t.data between '2016-06-01' and '2016-06-14'
group by 
    Dia
;
```

Se precisar da data completa, recomendo usar [`date_format`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) para ter dia/mês/ano em uma string só e agrupar por ela:

```
select
    date_format(t.data, '%d/%m/%Y') as 'Dia',
    count(*) as 'Quantidade'
from
    tabela t
where
    t.data between '2016-01-01' and '2016-06-14'
group by 
    Dia
;
```